# Questions about external SSD software RAID?

Tags: macos, backup, external-hard-drive, storage, software-raid

I currently have **two 2.5" 4TB SSDs**. My plan is to get an **external Thunderbolt enclosure** with a minimum of 4 bays and no hardware RAID (e.g. OWC Thunderbay Mini), and buy two more 4TB SSDs to make **two RAID 0 arrays** of 8TB each: one would be for storage and the other for backing up the first.
The arrays would be managed with software, either Disk Utility, SoftRAID, or something else. I don't want a NAS for various reasons!

As I understand it, if at one point the **enclosure goes somehow bad** and doesn't damage the drives in the process, the latter could still be transplanted into another enclosure, and used without needing to rebuild the array, right?

On the other hand, if the **internal storage of my mac gets somehow corrupted** or wiped, the software raid also goes out the window and the data is lost. I'd need to backup the mac to a third external drive, to be able to restore the system and thus software RAID setup and configuration?

I guess I could also put the four SSDs into a **RAID 5 array** of about 12TB, where one drive could get damaged, but the array rebuild with a new one. It somehow seems fishier to me, but the overall usable capacity would be larger.

What am I overlooking here? Is there something better to do with the 4 SSDs in terms of external storage?

Thanks.

Comment: RAID0 has no safety-net. Avoid.

Comment: @Tetsujin Also if I have two 8TB RAID arrays: one being for storage and the other for backup, meaning a copy of the storage array?

Comment: Your safety net for a RAID0 is one single spinny rust to back up to, not another RAID0. For sanity's sake, not in the same enclosure. Your backup doesn't need to be fast, merely reliable. [Your non-optional off-site 3rd copy can be heavily de-prioritised, from the first backup.]

Comment: @Tetsujin I'll rethink my strategy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there’s a little misunderstanding of RAID.

What you describe….Two RAID 0 arrays where one backs up the other is called RAID 0+1 or RAID 10. The two modes are different but essentially the same. They are both different than RAID 5 which is striping w/ parity. Each mode has its pros and cons. If you want maximum redundancy and performance you’ll need RAID 10 which comes at the largest cost because you can only use half the storage space available on the physical disks.

Now, if I’m misunderstanding and you actually want two independent RAID 0 arrays, what I’m about to say, still applies in all circumstances.

The RAID configuration is stored in metadata on the physical disks. Even though you may lose a controller / enclosure, or software raid configuration, the drives can be placed in a new enclosure or hooked to a new controller and the raid configuration can be rebuilt. As long as everything remains compatible, nothing is lost. To answer your question directly, NO, if your Mac fails you will not lose the data. But you will have to reconfigure the RAID again.